# styling the superfish mobile menu

Tags: routes, theming, navigation

is there any way to change the name of the superfish mobile menu that you get when viewing superfish on an iphone. its activated after you have set up your superfish menu by adding the path : sites/all/libraries/superfish/sfsmallscreen.js  to the setting on : admin/config/user-interface/superfish. I get "MAIN MENU" as my mobile responsive menu (see pic), and was wondering if I could get just "MENU" or even just show a button? Also is there a parameter that can be set for screen size, as I think the mobile menu is activated for an Ipad. I just wanted it for Phone. I'm using Drupal 7, Omega 3 theme, and the latest dev version of Superfish. [image]

Comment: i have found the parameter to activate mobile on screen width, its in the Block config for Superfish, under the Superfish Plugins configuration, SF SmallScreen then Window Width. Something else to note is that you need to click on "Enable jQuery sf-Touchscreen...." if you want your drop down menu to work on ipads or iphones. I guess it takes 'Main Menu' from the name of the menu, so an option would be to just rename your menu to just 'Menu'. You need to use the latest dev version of Superfish and Masterlibrary branch too.